# testing a site not working in internet explorer-values not able to enter in fields

Tags: protractor, cucumber

I am using protractor version 5.2.2 and cucumber-protractor framework, I have started practising testing for the LinkedIn site, but when I use the internet explorer browser it is only able to open the LinkedIn URL as mentioned in the config file and no scenarios are being executed, can anybody help me?

//config file

```
var params = require('./browsers.js');
var browser = params.browser;
var multiCapabilities = browser.split(',').map(function(browserName){
    return {
        browserName: browserName.trim()
    };
})

var moment = require('moment')
var timeStamp = moment().format('YYYYMMDD_hhmmss');

exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
  getPageTimeout: 60000,
  allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  multiCapabilities: multiCapabilities,

 // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
 // protractor is called.
 specs: ['Features/*.feature'],

 baseUrl: 'https://www.linkedin.com/',

 cucumberOpts: {
    require: 'Features/step_definition/searchstep_linkedin.js',
    tags: false,
    plugin: ['pretty'],
    format: 'json:reports/report'+timeStamp+' '+browser+'/results.json',
    profile: false,
    'no-source': true
},

 plugins: [{
    package: 'protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin',
    options:{
        automaticallyGenerateReport: true,
    }
}]
```

};

//Feature file

```
Background: I need to go linked in site
     Given I go to url ""

Scenario: Should not login with blank username and password
    Then I wait for "2000"
    When I enter " " in "#login-email"
    When I enter " " in "#login-password"
    Then I click on "#login-submit"
    Then I should see ""
```

//Spec File

```
Given(/^I go to url "(.*)"$/, function (url){       
    return browser.get(url);
});

When(/^I enter "(.*)" in "(.*)"$/, function (value,locator){        /**/
    return element(by.xpath(locator)).sendKeys(value);
});

Then(/^I should see "(.*)"$/, function (url){       /**/
    browser.sleep(2000);
    return 
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal(browser.baseUrl 
         + url);
});

Then(/^I click on "(.*)"$/, function (locator){     /**/
    return return element(by.xpath(locator)).click();
});
```

Comment: What is your error output, and do your tests work on other browsers?

Comment: sure @Ben Mohorc , my tests do work on chrome and firefox perfectly, but when it comes to IE it just opens the base url site ie; Linkedin and is just stuck there not entering any values in the textfield and after some time gives the timeout error, i think its probably with some settings in internet explorer can u help me fix it?

Comment: Can you edit the question and add your conf.js code and the relevant portion of your spec.

Comment: yeah done, please see to it that i m using protractor-cucumber framework